# How to find millions of MongoDB records then post them to AW SQS using Node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, amazon-sqs

I'm currently working on the billing system for my app. The general idea is have a billing cycle that plays out like so:

---

**THE METHODOLOGY**

1. `CRON` Triggers `POST api.myapp.com/Harvest` to kick off the billing cycle
2. `API Billing.Harvest()` finds all accounts and sends their `accountID` to `SQS Reap-Queue`
3. `SQS Reap-Queue` receives all `accountID`'s from `Billing.Harvest()`
4. `API Billing.Reap()` listens to `SQS Reap-Queue`, receives the `accountID`'s, gathers data from the `Usage` DB, and posts the usage data to `SQS Tally-Queue`
5. `SQS Tally-Queue` receives usage data from `Billing.Reap()`
6. `API Billing.Tally()` listens to `SQS Tally-Queue`, receives the usage data, calculates a monthly invoice, and sends the invoice data to `SQS Invoice-Queue`
7. `SQS Invoice-Queue` receives the invoice data from `Billing.Tally()`
8. `API Billing.Invoice()` listens to `SQS Invoice-Queue`, receives the invoice data, generates an invoice in the `Invoices` DB, attempts a charge against the account, and updates the `Accounts` DB accordingly.

---

**THE PROBLEM**

The problem I'm running into happens in Step 2, where I'm attempting to `Accounts.find()` millions of documents from mongo and then send the `_id` to Step 3, the `SQS Reap-Queue`.

Specifically, my server becomes unresponsive around document `33,000`, is flagged as 'unhealthy' by my `ELB Load Balancer` health-check, and is terminated.

When I run `top` on my server the information it gives me for the `Billing.Harvest()` process is like so:

`PID  USER      PR  NI VIRT    RES      SHR  S %CPU %MEM   TIME+ COMMAND`

`2479 ubuntu    20   0 1635132 678180   2280 R 99.2 66.7   0:31.56 node`

<strike>So the CPU is konking out on my little `t2.micro` test instance.</strike>

> **CORRECTION:** The problem actually wasn't with the CPU, it was running out of RAM. Trying to load 3M docs into my t2.micro 1Gb of RAM
>   apparently isn't a good idea. A streaming cursor is the ideal solution
>   if you simply need to move docs from Mongo to wherever. I happen to
>   need to update the `timeout` on any given doc (to ensure no other
>   process picked it up), so I ended up using `findAndModify`, which is
>   much slower, and memory-intensive, but it does the trick.

---

**IS A DISTRIBUTED SOLUTION POSSIBLE?**

Typically the solution to this problem would be to distribute the load across several machines. However, I must run `Billing.Harvest()` on a single machine in order to gather the initial set of `accountID`s that I need to send to SQS to have processed. Once this step is passed, all the subsequent SQS queues will have several worker instances that will receive messages and process accordingly without burning through all the CPU on any given instance.

I just can't figure out how to run `Billing.Harvest()` without crashing my server.

> **UPDATE**: Yes, a distributed solution is possible by creating a script that polls the DB using `findAndModify` at a given interval and
>   with a reasonable `limit` depending on the RAM in your machine (I've
>   found that 10,000 docs every three minutes works well within the 1GB
>   of RAM in a t2.micro from AWS). I'll contribute a more comprehensive
>   answer once I've refined my solution.

---

**THE QUESTIONS**

1. <strike>Do I just need a bigger server with more CPU?</strike> Yes, that's great, but the real problem was running out of RAM.
2. Should I use `setTimeout` to add an artificial delay between `Accounts` DB calls and use `Accounts.findAndModify()` to find each record one-by-one and add a field to my documents to indicate that this `accoundID` was already Harvested for any given billing cycle? This seems brittle and messy to me.
3. Is it reasonable to expect Mongo to return 3,000,000 docs in my `Accounts.find()` query or should I be querying for smaller, more digestible data sets in several steps instead?

---

In short, how does any given telco handle this? Giant monolithic billing servers with 256 cores and Petabyte of RAM? Or is there a better, more elegant solution that can be achieved using tiny, commodity VPS instances?

Comment: Handling 3M doc result sets in one go is unreasonable.  Better to have `Billing.Harvest()` stream or batch up blocks of account IDs to the `SQS Reap Queue` instead of sending them all at once.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I thought I might be outside of Mongo best practices. Have an example or link of streaming or batch processing? I'm off to check that out now. Thanks!